# How force apache to use different IPs for fetching data from remote hosts

Tags: php, apache, ip, vps

I've installed apache2 on a VPS. My VSP has two valid IP addresses.
I'm using rapidleech on my server to download some files from some sharing sites e.g rapidshare.
My problem is that most of those sites are IP sensitive (I mean they don't allow parallel access via a single IP), so I want to use both of my VSP IPs to access a server at same time & parallel download two files!
How can I configure apache server to use different IPs when sends requests (via PHP scripts) to downloading servers?

Answer (score 1):

Since I suspect you are using cURL for the data transfer, look at

```
curl_setopt($curlresource , CURLOPT_INTERFACE , '111.222.333.444');
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a matter of configuring apache, but configuring routes.  How you do that is dependent on your platform.